# Only showing the_date and the_excerpt for first entry in get_posts

Tags: get-posts, array, date, excerpt, php

this code below shows the titles and links for 5 posts in get_posts no problem but only displays the date and excerpt for first post... any help please?

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'my',  
    'order_by' => 'post_date',
    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'mycategory',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array(36, 38, 83, 84),
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                    ),
                    ),
);
$last_five_posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $last_five_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" id="frontpagelatestposttitle"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    <div><?php the_date(); ?></div>
    <div id="frontpagelatestpostexcerpt"> <p>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    </p> </div>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: To do that replace `<?php the_date(); ?>` in your code with `<?php the_title(); ?>`.

Comment: OK, well it displays the_title for all of the posts... but I already have that. why do the_date and the_excerpt not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having same issue as I was having earlier. In this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166751/).

So here is the fixed code. This should work. I replaced both of these functions with `get_the_date` and `get_the_excerpt`. For the detailed explanation why/why not this work, read @kaiser's answer in same question.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'my',  
    'order_by' => 'post_date',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'mycategory',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array(36, 38, 83, 84),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ),
    ),
);
$last_five_posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $last_five_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" id="frontpagelatestposttitle"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    <div><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></div>
    <div id="frontpagelatestpostexcerpt">
        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)