# Loop through all posts in a certain year

Tags: loop, date

I would like to loop through all posts within a certain year. Pretty simple setup:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   // doing content stuff here 
<?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I limit this for all posts for the year of X?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: On which template is this. Got a feeling that you might not need a custom query

Answer (score 4):

You will have to run a custom query for that. Here is the query for displaying posts from a particular year. I have used year 2012 as an example.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
  'year'  => '2012',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

      the_content();

  endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: thanks, could you please do a simple output of `the_content();` in your example. Somehow it does not work for me! Appreciate!

Comment: I have updated the code and added `the_content()`. Please try again.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but I noticed a very weird behaviour on this snippet. When I use `the_date();` it only gives me a date on the LATEST post within the loop. Do you know why?

Comment: Use `<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>` instead of `the_date()`. Why it does not work, you can read more about it [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166751/post-doesnt-show-date-if-theres-another-post-with-the-same-date#answer-166766).

Comment: @user49869 I think Robert has solved your problem and provided you with a link that explains the `the_date()` issue, so please accept the answer to close the question, thanks.